# AVPlayerViewController doesn't maintain play/pause state while returning from full screen

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

I am using AVPlayerViewController in my application for half-screen and full-screen mode video.

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player
self.addChildViewController(playerController)
self.viewVideo.addSubview(playerController.view)
```

Everything works fine like switching from half-screen to full-screen mode maintain it's play/pause state as it is. But while switching from full-screen to half-screen video pauses every time. How can I maintain the state of play/pause even while exit fullscreen.

Comment: are you pausing anywhere in viewWillDisappear?

Comment: No, it doesn't pause programmatically from anywhere in my code.

Comment: your viewcontroller life cycle will get call everytime u comes from full screen to half screen...where did you added above code?

Comment: Yes, whenever I switch from half to full or full to half, my viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear calls properly. I added above code in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Do you  nil your player object anywhere ? or add more code

Comment: No, I didn't nil player from anywhere. But I think this is the default behaviour of player as I just checked Facebook in safari mobile. When I switch to full-screen video in safari and them when I exit video pause automatically.